# Mount NFS directory at boot

Tags: boot, nfs

I have a raspberry pi humming along happily. I'd like it to mount an NFS directory and so I've set up an `/etc/fstab` rule:

`192.168.1.4:/media    /mnt/media  nfs  rw,auto,hard,intr`

The directory exists locally and remotely. `sudo mount -a` as the "pi" user mounts it with no fuss.

My problem is that the directory does not seem to mount automatically if I reboot the pi. I don't want to boot off this directory or anything, I just want it to come up when I do boot.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here or possibly any pointers of things I should be looking at?

Comment: The problem is almost certainly due to the fact that the network interface is not initialised at the time fstab is executed. Many other seem to have similar problems, particularly with WiFi network. I suggest you put in a script that runs at log on time.

Comment: In my case, the network is ethernet, not WiFi. A login script won't work in my use case as I want a script at startup to be able to access the mount rather than a user logging in. I was unsure at what point the mount would be guaranteed available otherwise the startup script could handle this. I was worried that even if the startup script seemed to work, it may depend on a race condition that wouldn't always work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick and dirt hack would be to edit /etc/rc.local and add "mount /mnt/media". This will automatically be carried out on boot. The correct way, I think, would be to add the nfs-common init script to the default runlevel. This can be done by using the update-rc.d command.

```
sudo update-rc.d nfs-common enable
```

Comment: I tried your 'correct way' and it appears to do the trick.

Comment: running the command above return error: Failed to enable unit: Unit file /lib/systemd/system/nfs-common.service is masked.

Comment: should I also remove mount from /etc/fstab ? where I should add that mount command?

Comment: In both cases the line for the mount should remain in /etc/fstab.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem as you. In my case, running

```
sudo raspi-config
```

and selecting *Wait for network at boot/Yes* did the trick.

Comment: After doing what fred suggested and not having any joy I tried this and it worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another option (requiring a little more work) that you may want to look into is AutoFS.  AutoFS will allow you to configure mount points such that they are mounted automatically when the mount point is accessed and unmounted after some time of inactivity.  When using this with NFS it can help you reduce your network traffic by only keeping that connection open when it's needed.

http://greenfly.org/tips/autofs.html

http://linux.die.net/man/5/autofs

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Try the following solution, the last step might be what you want,

Get the uuid of the external hard drive with following command

```
sudo blkid
```

Add the entry into fstab so that when you restart the raspberry device it is auto mounted every time

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

> UUID=0A423D084xxxxxx /mnt/data ntfs defaults,noatime,auto 0 0

**Some explanation for above command** - I mounted it to **/mnt/data** directory. ( You need to create it first if doesn't exist with **sudo mkdir /mnt/data** ) Mine was a **NTFS** format. You might try only the **defaults** option. I added **noatime** and **auto** to experiment a few things. You can check more details about it on internet.

Some Raspberry device ( including mine ) needs one more addition ( optional, try only if above doesn't work ), after above command, add a **5 seconds delay** to loading the device as sometimes the Raspberry OS loads faster than external drive and external hard drive loads a little slower and need more time to start, in this case the external drive isn't auto mounted and it is skipped with an error at the start. Add the following property/value to the end of your **cmdline.txt inside /boot folder**

```
sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt
```

Add

> rootdelay=5

Hope it helps!

Comment: blkid is not applicable to mounting a remote filesystem via nfs.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here:

https://discourse.osmc.tv/t/nfs-kernel-server-wont-start-on-boot/5936/18

From the user "mandelsoft"

Create this file:
**/etc/systemd/system/nfs-kernel-server.service.d/10-dep.conf**

And within it:

```
[Unit]
Requires=rpcbind.service
After=rpcbind.service
```

I'm running on MATE for the pi.  So other OSes may give you different results, but on my system at least, this fixes the problem reliably.

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't seen all the updated answers on this thread, but managed to find a similar way to mount an NFS drive on my Raspberry Pi 4.

The main prob seems to be that the LAN/network interface is very late coming up / going active.

I added a `@reboot` on the 1st line of my crontab.

Then ran a small bash script ---

```
#!/bin/bash

pause 30
sudo mount -a
```

I'm sure this could be done better, poss the exact NFS mount command, so this bash file is merely running the mount command I previously had to run manually.