# How to write raspistill image to usb drive

Tags: image, storage, readwrite

I want to write an image with raspistill (or video with raspivid) to a folder on an usb drive, but get an error.

I connected my usb drive and found the storage location with `sudo blkid`: `/dev/sda1`. To auto mount it at startup I edited the "fstab" file: `sudo nano /etc/fstab` and added the line `/dev/sda1 /mnt vfat defaults 0 0`. Just in case I set the proper permissions `sudo chmod 775 /mnt`. I then rebooted the pi and created a folder `sudo mkdir /mnt/images`.

Now to create an image I go `raspistill -q 90 -t 1000 -o /mnt/images/test.jpg` but get the following error:

```
mmal: main: Error opening output file: /mnt/images/test.jpg~
No output file will be generated
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong as writing an image in the home directory works `raspistill -q 90 -t 1000 -o test.jpg`

Comment: what do you get if you run "touch /mnt/images/test.jpg"? does the empty file get created successfully?

Comment: It says "permission denied". However, I thought I set the right permissions with sudo chmod 775 /mnt?. ps: I am able to copy files to the folder, e.g. `cp test.jpg /mnt/images/test.jpg` works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect your issue is that you are mounting the vfat filesystem so that it is only accessible to the `root` user.

The vfat filesystem (being a very simple filesystem dating from the ancient days of DOS) has no concept of users and groups, but all files in UNIX systems *must* have an owner and group. To work around this, the Linux vfat driver defaults to making all directories and files on a mounted vfat filesystem owned by `root` (with group `root`). Mode 775 (which you set on the mount-point after mounting the partition) means that it should be writeable by the owner (in this case `root`) and by members of the group (also `root`), but not by "others" ... including your unprivileged `pi` user (which I assume you're logged on as).

Hence, running `raspistill -q 90 -t 1000 -o /mnt/images/test.jpg` fails, but I'd bet that running `sudo raspistill -q 90 -t 1000 -o /mnt/images/test.jpg` will work just fine (because `root` can write to `/mnt/images` but `pi` can't). You can also confirm this by running `ls -ld /mnt` which will probably show something like the following:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 30  2014 /mnt
```

A better solution that running everything with `sudo` would be to mount the partition so that all the files and directories on it appear to be owned by the `pi` user. This can be accomplished quite easily by tweaking your `/etc/fstab` entry. Just change the `defaults` item to `uid=pi,gid=pi` and reboot. In other words, the line should look like this afterward:

```
/dev/sda1 /mnt vfat uid=pi,gid=pi 0 0
```

Once you've rebooted you should find that `ls -ld /mnt` shows something like this instead:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Apr 30  2014 /mnt
```

At this point, your `raspistill` command should work without `sudo`.

Comment: You were exactly right. It indeed worked with sudo and changing the /etc/fstab entry did the trick after reboot. Thanks again!

Comment: ps: would it be possible to write images to a network (NAS) drive and if so how? I can't find this information anywhere.

Comment: @JolJols - certainly! If your NAS supports Windows file shares, have a look at [this question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8386/how-to-mount-time-capsule-from-raspberry-pi/8407#8407) for information on mounting CIFS shares (CIFS is the protocol used by Windows file sharing). Alternatively if it supports NFS (generally preferable but not as widely supported), take a look at [this question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14098/mount-nfs-directory-at-boot)